# Is there any way to create a table with the same layout as a view in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, view

I can't really think of the best way to phrase this question, so I'll just give an example.  Suppose I have a table that is created like this:

```
CREATE VIEW People
AS
    SELECT
        id, --int
        name, --varchar(20)
        birthdate --datetime
    FROM SomeTable
```

If I wanted to change this from a view to a physical table, is there any way to create a table with the same layout?

In other words, I want to take that view and create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE People(
    id int,
    name varchar(20),
    birtdate datetime
)
```

...but without having to manually write that query out.

This is of course a contrived example.  The view has a lot of fields with a lot of different data types, so it would be difficult to do by hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT * INTO MyNewTable FROM MyView
```

AND if you don't want the content, just the structure

```
SELECT * INTO MyNewTable FROM MyView WHERE 1 = 2
```

Comment: Thanks.  I figured it would be something simple.

Comment: +1, but just be aware that in some cases, especially when using calculated fields that return null, SQL will not pick the type for the field that you expected. You can use an explicit convert on the field in that case to work around the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
INTO People_Table
FROM People_View
```

Answer (score 1):

Select * INTO PeopleTable FROM People

Comment: Wrong syntax.  INTO must be before FROM.